# Gatsby Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <html> cannot appear as a child of <div>

Tags: javascript, gatsby

I'm learning to build Gatsby sites with several tutorials. I'm using Gatsby 2.13.50 (CLI: 2.7.14). Usually, these tutorials teach us to build a base template. It loads well except for this warning when I open dev tools to console:

```
Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <html> cannot appear as a child of <div>.
```

The warning is very, very long. I'll post the rest of it after my code.

My layout.js base template is at /src/components/layout.js. It looks like this:

```
import React from "react"

const Layout = (props) => {
    return (
        <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <Helmet>
                    <meta charSet="utf-8" />
                    <title>Demo</title>
                </Helmet>
            </head>

            <body>
                {props.children}
            </body>
        </html>
    )
}

export default Layout
```

It is used by /src/pages/index.js, which looks like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import Layout from '../components/layout'

const IndexPage = () => {
    return (
        <Layout>
            <h1>Demo onle.</h1>
            <p>Hello. This totally works fine.</p>
        </Layout>
    )
}

export default IndexPage
```

As mentioned, it works, except for the very long warning in dev tools console.

I've googled this but haven't found out how this happens and what to do to avoid it. I found out that there's a [html.js](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/custom-html/) but I don't know if this is some sort of default template and if I should override it to use as a base template. I tried that but the performance is very bad, so I think I'm wrong.

When I remove the `<html>` tag, I get: `Parsing error: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag.`

If I replace it with a `<div>` It says `<body> cannot appear as a child of <div>`

Here is the very long warning:

```
Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <html> cannot appear as a child of <div>.
    in html (at layout.js:10)
    in Layout (at chat.js:6)
    in ChatPage (created by HotExportedChatPage)
    in AppContainer (created by HotExportedChatPage)
    in HotExportedChatPage (created by PageRenderer)
    in PageRenderer (at json-store.js:93)
    in JSONStore (at root.js:51)
    in RouteHandler (at root.js:73)
    in div (created by FocusHandlerImpl)
    in FocusHandlerImpl (created by Context.Consumer)
    in FocusHandler (created by RouterImpl)
    in RouterImpl (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Location (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Router (created by EnsureResources)
    in ScrollContext (at root.js:64)
    in RouteUpdates (at root.js:63)
    in EnsureResources (at root.js:61)
    in LocationHandler (at root.js:119)
    in LocationProvider (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Location (at root.js:118)
    in Root (at root.js:127)
    in _default (at app.js:65)
__stack_frame_overlay_proxy_console__ @ index.js:2177
warningWithoutStack @ react-dom.development.js:507
validateDOMNesting @ react-dom.development.js:8625
createInstance @ react-dom.development.js:8737
completeWork @ react-dom.development.js:16901
completeUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:19143
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:19341
workLoop @ react-dom.development.js:19353
renderRoot @ react-dom.development.js:19436
performWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:20343
performWork @ react-dom.development.js:20255
performSyncWork @ react-dom.development.js:20229
requestWork @ react-dom.development.js:20098
scheduleWork @ react-dom.development.js:19912
enqueueSetState @ react-dom.development.js:11170
./node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js.Component.setState @ react.development.js:335
(anonymous) @ index.js:104
requestAnimationFrame (async)
(anonymous) @ index.js:102
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ index.js:100
(anonymous) @ history.js:70
navigate @ history.js:69
(anonymous) @ navigation.js:103
Promise.then (async)
navigate @ navigation.js:77
window.___navigate @ navigation.js:150
navigate @ index.js:213
onClick @ index.js:184
onClick @ index.js:464
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:150
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:200
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:257
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:271
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:562
executeDispatchesInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:584
executeDispatchesAndRelease @ react-dom.development.js:681
executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel @ react-dom.development.js:689
forEachAccumulated @ react-dom.development.js:663
runEventsInBatch @ react-dom.development.js:817
runExtractedEventsInBatch @ react-dom.development.js:825
handleTopLevel @ react-dom.development.js:4827
batchedUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:20440
batchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:2152
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:4906
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:20491
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:255
interactiveUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:20490
interactiveUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:2171
dispatchInteractiveEvent @ react-dom.development.js:4883
```

How should I fix this warning?

Comment: Try replacing both BODY and HTML tags with DIV

Comment: @eddiewould it looks like replacing HTML, BODY, and HEAD tags with DIV worked. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. Create `pages/_document.js`

   ```
    import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';
    export default class CustomDocument extends Document {
      render() {
      <Html lang="en">
        <Head>
          <Helmet>
            <meta charSet="utf-8" />
            <title>Demo</title>
          </Helmet>
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
   ```

   }
   }
2. Update `src/components/layout.js`

   ```
    import React from 'react';

    const Layout = (props) => {
      return <>{props.children}</>;
    };

    export default Layout;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

you can not insert    tags inside the div they should be before any other tag. your index.html already has HTML BODY HEAD tag. if you look the index.js your component will render inside some root div. so use div instead of body tag and style like a body.